# How is this example related to Lamport clock theory? I can't relate algorithm example with the algorithm theory. Share some insights please

Tags: distributed-systems, computer-networks

[image: This is the example]

I have asked 1 type of question but I have asked that in many questions. So bear with me. My question is about 1 topic, I just didn't find it right to create separate questions for each of these questions so I am asking like this-:

The Lamport logical clock algorithm is-:

at pi : before each event Li= Li + 1
when pi  sends a message m to pj

1. pi: ( Li = Li + 1 ); t = Li ; message = (m, t) ;
2. pj: Lj = max(Lj, t); Lj= Lj+ 1;
3. Lj (receive event) = Lj ;

**Here is my question-:**

A) p1->p2-:

Here we have message m1.

Lj=max(6,16)=16

**Q1) Now We need to do Lj=Lj+1 isn't it according to the algorithm?** So Lj=17 isn't it??

Then
B) p2->p3

For m2-:

Lj=max(24,40)=40

**Q2) Lj=Lj+1=41. Isn't it? Why are we not doing it?**

C) p3->p2

For m3-:
Lj=max(60,56)=60

Lj=Lj+1=61

**Q3) But why did we updated 64 to 69, 72 to 77 and 80 to 85 in P2? Which part of Lamport's logical clock is happening here?**

d) p2->p1-:

For m4-:

Lj=max(54,69)=69

Lj=Lj+1=70

**Q4) But why did we updated 60 to 76? Which part of algorithm are we following here?**

Comment: Only one question per post, please.